# How can I "close" an enumerator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, enumerator

I have an enumerator that loops on data from an external API. The API requests that I notify it when I'm done looping. This is pretty easy when the enumerator is allowed to go until it runs out of data:

```
def api_enum
  return enum_for(:api_enum) unless block_given?
  loop_on_api_calls { |thing| yield thing }
  notify_api_that_i_am_done
end
```

But what about this case?

```
api_enum.each do |thing|
  do_stuff(thing)
  break
end
```

The `break` means I'm never going to call `notify_api_that_i_am_done`. How could I structure this to guarantee that `notify_api_that_i_am_done` gets called? Is there a good pattern to for this?

Comment: What is wrong with `break notify_api_that_i_am_done`?

Comment: @spickermann I honestly did not know that was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `break` with an argument:

```
api_enum.each do |thing|
  do_stuff(thing)
  break(notify_api_that_i_am_done)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `api_enum` method, you can use `ensure` to always execute cleanup code, regardless of any exception being thrown or the user `break`ing. This is a good idea to use for any cleanup code since only tht way you can ensure that the it us run even if something raises an exception in the user-supplied block.

This can be used like this:

```
def api_enum
  return enum_for(:api_enum) unless block_given?
  loop_on_api_calls { |thing| yield thing }
ensure
  notify_api_that_i_am_done
end
```

With that pattern, you don't need to follow any special call conventions.